# Pattern matching in if block in Alpine's `sh`

Tags: shell, alpine-linux

How do i replicate the following bash expression:

```bsh
if [[ "$foo" =~ (bar|spam) ]]; then
  echo "True"
fi
```

in Alpine's `/bin/sh`?

Typing it in as-is throws an error:

```
/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "then")
```

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like the `sh` you are using is Busybox `ash`. Can you please confirm this is the case? While a POSIX `sh` would not have a `[[` construct, Busybox `ash` supports it and `if [[ "$foo" =~ \(bar\|spam\) ]]; then ...` may work for you.

Comment: I can confirm that it is. I also tested your example and can confirm that it works. Feel free to post it as an answer since it might help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test whether your shell variable `foo` contains the substring `bar` or `spam`, then you may do that with a standard `case ... esac` statement.

```bsh
case $foo in
    *bar*|*spam*) echo True
esac
```

If you want a "catch-all" case, use a separate case at the end with the pattern `*`.

```bsh
case $foo in
    *bar*|*spam*) echo True ;;
    *) echo False
esac
```

Note that the patterns used by `case ... esac` are shell globbing patterns, not regular expressions.  As such, the patterns need to match the whole string, so we use `*` around each substring to allow for other characters on either side.  Each case in the `case ... esac` statement uses a `|`-separated list of patterns and a list of statements to execute when a pattern from that list matches.  The statements for a case are terminated by `;;` (you may omit this for the last case). The shell executes the code for the first case with a pattern that matches.

You may also write the second code block above  as

```bsh
case $foo in (*bar*|*spam*) echo True ;; (*) echo False; esac
```

The left parenthesis of the pattern is always optional.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on discord helped me out with this.

The snippet in the question can be replicated using the `case` statement:

```bsh
case "$foo" in
(bar|spam) echo "True";;
esac
```

Comment: Yes, roughly, but note that the right hand side of the `=~` operator in the `[[...]]` construct is an extended regular expression, while the expression in parentheses in the `case` construct is a shell pattern. Specifically relevant in this case, the `case` pattern `bar|spam` would be equivalent to the regular expression `^bar$|^spam$` (note the anchoring), while the pattern `*bar*|*spam*` would be equivalent to the regular expression `bar|spam`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Though the `case` behavior is exactly what i was looking for in this case. It's good to know that it doesn't have "real regex" capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$foo" = bar ] || [ "$foo" = spam ]; then
  echo "True"
fi
```

Comment: The actual script is more complex than the example in the question. I just posted a simplified case to make it easier to understand. So, although this would work if there were only these two cases. It's not really viable in the "real" script

Comment: An unanchored regular expression matches anywhere in the text. Your tests are for equality.